# TinyMCE - disable resize for one editor (out of three on page)

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have three TinyMCE editors on a page. I want two of them to be resizeable, but not the third. Is it possible to disable the resize handle for just one editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the `resize` configuration option?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#resize

Here is an example:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/GKfaab

Comment: Please see the fiddle I added to my answer: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/GKfaab  The first editor cannot be resized and the second can.